# Microsoft ANGLE for uwp

Tags: c++, opengl-es, uwp, windows-10-universal, universal

guys! I'm currently working on new cross-platform application (iOS, Android, UWP). I have graphical library for UI written in c++, using freeglut for opengGL. 
The problem is, I don't know how to use this library in my UWP application. I have read a lot of information about all the wrappers for OpenGL, but they all for WPF or written in C++. I also know about Microsoft ANGLE Project, but it is written in the c++ too, but I need to write the application in C# language.

So, how can I modify my own library using excluding freeglut and import it into my C# application?

By the way, sorry for mistakes in my English.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to consume your legacy C++ assembly in your UWP application?

You can create a Windows Runtime Component(Universal Windows) project, in which you need to include the assembly, and declare as many APIs as you want to expose, all marked with [DllImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx) attribute.

Eventually, this WinRT component will do the [Platform Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx), and works as a "wrapper" layer between your legacy code and UWP application.

It's up to your preference which language you use for the WinRT component, C++ or C#, either way, you need to worry about struct/type [mashalling and unmashalling.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx)

After you're done with above, you'll be able to reference the WinRT component in your UWP application, and call the APIs you declared in that assembly.

The same way works for Microsoft Angle project as well.

You might find this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx#BK_WinRTComponent) useful.

One last word, you might want to avoid using forbidden APIs, otherwise your UWP app won't pass the Windows Store Certification.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/jj714080.aspx there is an option to use DirectX and some native API functions including LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/jj714080.aspx
This should give you ability to use any native dll.
You can try to make RuntimeComponent project and put it there. Also you can try clr oldsyntax option to use native code as it is.